# Mootools set radio button checked

Tags: javascript, mootools

I have 2 radio buttons

and I used mootool while loading as

```
 window.addEvent('domready', function() {
   var chk="1";
 if(chk==1){

$('edit-gender-0').set('checked',true);
 }

else if(chk==2){
 $('edit-gender-1').set('checked',true);

  }
```

but it is not working at all.

Any help will be appreciated... and any other short solution without the if-condition.

Comment: I dunno, but it bothers me that you quoted your "1" when you assigned it to `chk` but not in your if statements. The first is a string, the others are ints. Can't remember if it matters in JS but still !!

Comment: Yeah, it bothers me too...But i don't matter in JS.
"5" == 5 //true
"5" === 5 //false

Comment: so what will be the solution for integer and string is it sensitive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you've provided works just fine - here's a test-case: http://jsfiddle.net/oskar/tM29a/

Answer (score 2):

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
   var chk="1";
   if(chk==1){
      $('edit-gender-0').set('checked',true);
   } else if(chk==2){
      $('edit-gender-1').set('checked',true);
});
```

don't forget to add }); at the end of the addEvent function.